# Scipy: Two ways of implementing a differential equation: two different solutions: answered

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations

I was trying to solve a differential equation for my thesis in chemistry and there I stumbled over a question regarding the differential equation solver "odeint" of scipy.

First I implemented the differential by the function CIDNP_1 (CIDNP is a chemical phenomena, that explains the unusual variables) according the the example on the scipy website. But the solution is way off even the right direction.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate

R0 = 5e+5
kt = 5e5/R0
beta = 3/R0

def CIDNP_1(y, t):
    dP_dt, dQ_dt = y

    def R(t):
        return R0/(1 + kt*R0*t)

    dP_dt = -kt*dP_dt*R(t) - kt*beta*(R(t))**2
    dQ_dt = +kt*dP_dt*R(t) + kt*beta*(R(t))**2
    return [dP_dt, dQ_dt]


def CIDNP_2(y, t):    
    dP_dt, dQ_dt = y

    def R(t):
        return R0/(1 + kt*R0*t)

    return [-kt*dP_dt*R(t) - kt*beta*(R(t))**2, \
            +kt*dP_dt*R(t) + kt*beta*(R(t))**2]

y0 = [-1, +1]
t = np.linspace(1e-9, 100e-6, 1e3)
sol_1 = scipy.integrate.odeint(CIDNP_1, y0, t)
sol_2 = scipy.integrate.odeint(CIDNP_2, y0, t)
```

Then I altered my solution to CIDNP_2 what gave the correct result but in my eyes there is no difference in the implementation as the variables dP_dt and dQ_dt are not altered in implementation CIDNP_1.

So as anyone can give me a hint why the implementation CIDNP_1 gives the wrong result I'd be very lucky as then at least the last two hours weren't completely lost.

Regards,

Jakob

Comment: Are you sure that the input `y` is semantically a time derivative and not just the state `y=[P,Q]`resp. `P,Q = y`? This relabeling would also avoid the confusion from occurring.

Comment: Semantivally you are right. The differential equation describes the state and no derivative of the system. But as I initially just wanted to code within five minutes I didn't put much thought into this. In a next version I will alter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version you perform the updates not at the same time, as you execute the to lines

```
dP_dt = -kt*dP_dt*R(t) - kt*beta*(R(t))**2
dQ_dt = +kt*dP_dt*R(t) + kt*beta*(R(t))**2
```

not simulatnously; therefore, you use the already updated `dP_dt` to update `dQ_dt`. This is a faulty implementation of the `ODE` system. Your second approach is better, as it does not have this kind of error. You either have to return the updated values directly, or you have to save the newly calculated values of `dP_dt` in another variable before calculating the new `dQ_dt`.

```
new_dP_dt = -kt*dP_dt*R(t) - kt*beta*(R(t))**2
new_dQ_dt = +kt*dP_dt*R(t) + kt*beta*(R(t))**2

return [new_dP_dt, new_dQ_dt]
```

this would solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. The next time I will try not to overwrite my variable within the same line. Regards

Answer (score 1):

In `CIDNP_1` you change the value of `dP_dt` before using the new value to calculate `dQ_dt`:

```
dP_dt = -kt*dP_dt*R(t) - kt*beta*(R(t))**2   # changed dP_dt!
dQ_dt = +kt*dP_dt*R(t) + kt*beta*(R(t))**2   # use the changed value!
```

In `CIDNP_2` you calculate them simultaneously, ie `dQ_dt` is calculated with the original value of `dP_dt`, not the changed one. You can think of it like

```
a = -kt*dP_dt*R(t) - kt*beta*(R(t))**2       # no overwriting -
b = +kt*dP_dt*R(t) + kt*beta*(R(t))**2       # uses original value of dP_dt
return [a, b]
```

You could also probably speed things up a bit like

```
def CIDNP_3(y, t):
    dP_dt, dQ_dt = y
    R_t = R0 / (1 + kt * R0 * t)
    res = kt * R_t * (dP_dt + beta * R_t)
    return [-res, res]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The next time I will try not to overwrite my variable within the same line. Regards